# Redirect index.html to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am new to HTACCESS File.

Please tell me how to Redirect http://website.com/index.html to http://website.com/ through .htaccess file.

Regards,

Shashikant

Comment: Is this a case where you actually have a `index.html` file but you want to make sure that it is only accessible at the uri `/`?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this I believe:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You should also learn to google these things because this is quite common question.

Comment: I've tried this snippets and it works on my end, Thanks for this